# How to insert jQuery into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert

So, I need to make the following work:

```
var example = 0;
some code...
function example() {
    if (example === idk) {
         $('#id').example("1");
    }else{
         $('#id').example("2");
    }
}
```

I need to have normal javascript work with single jQuery lines here and there, but when I use jQuery it won't let me use any javascript without `.each()` with I don't want to need.  None of the above code is real it's just an example.

Comment: first include the jQuery library `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: Normal javascript works with single jQuery lines here and there already. So if its not working for you, check your console for errors. Your example should work fine without wrapping in each() functions.

Comment: Except that you've included <br>s in there??? Also, ".example()" is not a jQuery function so if you've literally put that there, things are going to break.

Comment: @relic180 i think since he says its just example code he was probably just trying to format the post with html tags.

Comment: really not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: *"...it's just an example"* An example of what??? `if (example === idk) {...` is comparing the `example` function to some unknown value. Please post a real example. This one makes no sense at all.

Comment: i already added the library. the example was to show normal code with a single jQuery line here and there

Comment: That's not normal code, and it doesn't illustrate anything useful. If you're actually having a problem, you need to post the problematic code in such a matter that it represents a full working demonstration of the issue. Saying *"a single jQuery line here and there"* is as useful as saying *"I have a line of JavaScript here and there that breaks my code, tell me what's wrong"*. How can we tell what's wrong if you post code that has nothing to do with the actual problem?

Comment: ...something tells me you don't understand what jQuery is. It's not a separate programming language. It's just a library of pre-written JavaScript code packaged together that you can use. If you wrote a bunch of JavaScript functions, put them in a file, gave it a name, and let people include it in their projects, it's still ultimately just JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#id')` does not return an DOM element.  It returns another jQuery object that contains 0, 1 or more DOM elements.

You could try  `$('#id')[0]` to get the first element in the collection...assuming there is one.

Comment: nononono.  The example means nothing, i've seen it work in Candy Box 2 for example, just normal javascript code and every once in a while some jquery

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery selector always returns a special jQuery object.

To get the underlying DOM element (or any of the elements in the set of matched elements if more than 1 element was matched by the selector), use the jQuery `.get()` function.

For example `$("div.box").get(0)` returns the DOM reference to the first matched `DIV` with class name `'box'`.

You can then apply "plain" JavaScript to that DOM reference.